# Windows limiting my network upload speed (Windows 10, 7)

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, modem

I need a little help about my issue with upload speed. So, I 've been having problems with my upload speed for months now. I noticed it when I tried livestreaming and I thought it was a server-side/host issue. So I tried a lot of tests (ookla, testmy, google drive upload/dropbox even youtube streaming) all have the same upload speed 0.9-1.3Mbps. However, when I tried to speedtest on my iPad or my Android Phone -- it's hitting 40-50Mbps upload with consistent results. Now I know that it's probably my computer having some issues.

So I tried a lot of things:

Used wired/wireless connection (different cards)
Updated/roll back network drivers (WiFi and Lan), Disabled/Enabled QoS, IPV6, etc.
Changed DNS (Cloudflare & Google)
Proxy Settings, Windows settings VPN all disabled
Disabled Windows Auto Tuning, Disabled (LSO) Large Send Offload
Set Duplex Settings to Max Full Duplex
Tried TCP Optimizer
Booted on Safe Mode with Networking

All have same results. So I thought, it wasn't Windows probably some networking routing whatever. Then I tried running Linux (kali) live on my PC -- the results were as advertised. 80-100Mbps upload and download using Wired/Wireless. And now I know it's not my hardware. I also tried booting a Windows 7 Laptop and run a speedtest, it got same result on my Windows PC 0.9-1.3Mbps upload.

I literally have no idea what else to with this. I now know this is a Windows issue 'cause some of my neighbors are also experiencing this issue. I told them to run a speedtest on various devices and told me that the upload speed slowdown happened in their Windows system. Really weird, right? I checked the modem settings, reset to defaults and still no luck. There's no QoS or any other filtering, limiting bandwidth enabled. MTU was set to 1500 (no issues with latency, etc).

Comment: So I tried a lot of things:  ...   Used wired/wireless connection (different cards) Updated/roll back network drivers (WiFi and Lan), Disabled/Enabled QoS, IPV6, etc. Changed DNS (Cloudflare & Google) Proxy Settings, Windows settings VPN all disabled Disabled Windows Auto Tuning, Disabled (LSO) Large Send Offload Set Duplex Settings to Max Full Duplex Tried TCP Optimizer Booted on Safe Mode with Networking    <--- See if you can get a plain Windows 10 machine (can you reset one?).  In my experience with Windows 10 , Windows 10 is not an issue.

Comment: This is almost always some 3rd party software, security or antivirus most likely... I do networking engineering for an ISP that has internet service over 2.5Gbps and we need to be able to test it, it's a real struggle with Windows PCs using our corporate security software. Messing with all those settings on the adapter and stuff isn't going to gain you anything noticeable, set them all back to default. Also, testing Internet speeds via WiFi is about as inaccurate as it gets.

Answer (score -1):

This could be an issue with you antivirus, assuming you got one. Most antivirus are packed with browsing and network protection. If you have one try to disable it.

Comment: Nope. It's not that, I disabled everything like I said on my post and ran windows on safe mode with networking. Still the same result.